# How to export and then apply code changes in GIT?

Tags: git

suppose I have 3 files tracked by GIT which have been modified.

```
fileA.py
fileB.py
fileC.py
```

When I enter "GIT diff --color...", I see the code modifications.

Suppose I would like to save the code changes for each file separately -> remove the my local repository -> clone GIT again -> apply the code changes again...

How can I export export the code modification done for each file to a separate file?

```
fileADiff.py
fileBDiff.py
fileCDiff.py
```

How to apply the changes after git cloning?

Thanks,

Qwerty

Comment: why not creating 3 commits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood correctly your point, After you made commit with changes from these files, you can create 3 patch for every file changes with:

```
git diff HEAD~..HEAD fileA.py > fileA.patch
```

It will create `fileA.patch` with your changes. And than you can apply your patches with

```
git apply fileA.patch
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I did not commit the files yet...What can I do?

Comment: Did you add your files to index, with git add?

Comment: Yes, I used Git add so GIT will track them. What can I do?

Comment: ok, now you can just add --cached option to git diff, like git diff --cached Head~..HEAD and etc... it will create patches with changes between your index and last commit